# Detect xhr.status === 0 in axios

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, axios

## Context

I have a web app running in a corporate environment where all requests go through a proxy that I have no control over. This layer automatically redirects my users to a single-sign-on page on a different domain as needed.

Here's the basic sequence:

1. User types `myapp.example.corp` into their browser
2. Request goes through proxy, which checks if the user is signed in
3. User isn't signed in, so they are redirected to sign-in at `auth.example.corp`
4. User signs in and is then redirected to my app

So far so good.

## The problem

The problem I want to ask about arises in the following scenario:

5. User does some work in my app, then goes home, leaving browser tab open
6. Some amount of times passes and the user's session expires
7. User returns to browser tab with my app is open and resumes using it
8. My app makes AJAX requests, and they go through the same proxy
9. Because the user is no longer signed in, these requests are redirected to the sign-in page
10. Because that sign-in page is on a different domain, the following is logged to the browser console, which is great for understanding what is happening

```
Failed to load https://auth.example.corp: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://myapp.example.corp'
is therefore not allowed access.
```

(This question is not about CORS. I cannot control the proxy or auth server. Please don't get distracted. )

The real problem is that in my application code where I'm using axios, the callbacks I pass to axios never get called. The promises for this request never get resolved or rejected. Nothing happens at all that I can detect in my code.

```js
// none of these callbacks get called
axios
  .get("/signedin")
  .then(response => console.log("Signed in"))
  .catch(response => console.log("Not signed in"))
```

## A workaround

If I instead use the `XMLHttpRequest` API, I'm able to detect this situation because an `onreadystatechange` event fires and I can test for `request.status === 0`.

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = event => {
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 0) {
    console.log("Not signed in");
  }
};
request.open("GET", "/signedin");
request.send();
```

## The question

So my question is: I'd really like to continue using axios but be able to detect this situation. Is there some way of detecting `xhr.status == 0` while using axios or am I forced to use `XMLHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CORS is the issue, whenever a preflight request fails browser will totally deny access to things like the return status code,response body and headers.That's why axios will never know of this and might be the reason why the promise is not closing it's somewhat similar to a network failure without any timeout limit.
But you can try interceptor like this to detect such conditions

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => response, (error) => {
  if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
      //alert the failure
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Works as advertised. Thanks, @Viney!