# Axios shows status code of 0 instead of 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

I've been trying to capture the response of requests through `axios` response interceptors.

I have a request that requires authorization; and when the authorization token is valid, the request executes successfully and returns the data with no issues.

However, when the token is expired and the server/backend responds with `403`; the **Network** tab in **DevTools** shows a `403` and `axios` shows a `0` status code with CORS issue in the **Console**.

I know it's not CORS because I have a wildcard allowance on it, the request works fine when the token is valid, and the pre-flight for this returns `200`.

### Screenshots:

#### Network Tab

1. [image: Network Tab]
2. [image: Preflight]
3. [image: Request]

#### Console Tab

1. [image: Console]
2. [image]

Comment: The console complaints about cors, its cors.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341222/detect-xhr-status-0-in-axios

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with **AWS Chalice's local environment**. You might be using something else that suffers from this. Here's the issue:

With the first request (options), they add `access-control-allow-origin`, but when the second request fails, they forget to add the header `access-control-allow-origin`, so it ends up in this awkward situation.

So, it's a CORS issue, but it's confusing because one has it and another doesn't.